# How much can openCV.js be reduced to improve loading time?

Tags: javascript, opencv, computer-vision

I'm working on a web based AR project, and rely on openCV for most image processing tasks. I only use functions of the "core" and "image processing" modules, so I'd like to compile a minimum version of openCV.js with just the basics, because loading the entire 9mb library is far too long.

I've built the library from the official repository and managed to remove enough modules to go down to 4.4mb, which I believe is still too long. However, I didn't manage to remove everything that my project didn't use, so I was wondering if anyone had gone deeper into the build process and managed to drop below this size, keeping the "core" and "image processing modules".

Comment: I have the same problem. How did you reduce the file size from 9 to 4.4mb?